# Hundreds of Red Spiders in Individual Webs

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I live in the USA in south Louisiana. I woke up this morning to find my yard covered in hundreds of spider webs.

[image]

Each of those little white puffs is a spider web. Inside of each web is one little red spider.
[image]

The spiders are pretty small. Less than half an inch long.[image]

Anyone know what they are?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/8/

Comment: @CDspace Seriously, there's an XKCD for absolutely everything...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a black-tailed red sheetweaver, *Florinda coccinea*.

Identified by its red body colour , location (USA) and black caudal 
tubercle.

[image: Image1]

More images to be found on [bugguide.net](http://bugguide.net/node/view/67291/bgimage)

> It is a species of web-building spider belonging to the family Linyphiidae. It is the only species in the genus Florinda. It is sometimes known as the red grass spider. This species is common in the southeastern United States, inhabiting grasslands, lawns, and agricultural fields.

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacktailed_red_sheetweaver)

Comment: You say "*It's a **rare** species.*", but the quoted text says "*This species is **common** in the southeastern United States*" could you please clarify?

Comment: Rare worldwide and common in a location.

Comment: I have seen these suckers before. Usually their web is most visible in the early morning when the grass is dew covered.  They seem to need a lot of space. I have seen them in large yards and fields but never small yards. There a little neat, but mostly harmless. Birds should come soon and eat most of them. You should try to avoid mowing them. I'd be surprised if they were there for more then a couple of days, assuming your don't have a mosquito problem.

Comment: @anothersackofchemicals Thanks for pointing out. It was my mistake to put it in that way. I actually meant they are rare worldwide as coteyr said. I've removed it.

Comment: Hey, I saw a couple of these in my yard just this morning. [This one missed a meal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eZgkzkLCr8)

Comment: @WayneWerner I loved the plot twist at the end of your video. It was like deus ex machina, or *dog* ex machina :-)

Comment: Cat ex-machina, actually. She decided that I should be petting *her* instead of taking videos of boring grey patches on the ground.

Comment: @coteyr Yeah, they were gone when I got back from work that evening.